# Special chars in serialized object are destroying PHP session

Tags: php, session, serialization, special-characters

After login of the user I serialize the user object and store it in his session just like this

```
$_SESSION['User'] = serialize($this);
```

so I have faster access to his data in further steps.

Now, sometimes users can't stay logged in because their session is immediatly destroyed with the next page request. I found that it is because of special chars the user stored in his data. E.g. in one case there were some sweet hards in a notice

```
s:72:"♥ Aufsicht ♥ <br>...;"
```

In another case a phone number was copied from Apple contacts and so on. 
Are there restrictions to storing in sessions, like only ASCII chars? Do I have to convert the whole string in another format, e.g. Base64? Or how to handle this best?
Thanx.

Comment: Is your website in UTF-8?

Comment: Is the session actually being set? Do you get any errors? Please post a minimal demonstrative example.

Comment: Yes, please give us a realistic example. That string cannot be 72 bytes long.

Comment: Yes website is all in UTF-8. The session is correct set, works with a lot of users very fine. And the string is only a small piece of a large string, just the part with the special chars to illustrate. Hmm, I'll try to make an example..

Comment: 1. You don't have to pre-serialize data you put into `$_SESSION`, that's the session handler's job. 2. There's still no reason for it to cause the behaviour you've described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot to Sammitch for the note in his comment: problem was the pre-serialization. If I just assign the object to the `$_SESSION` like

```
$_SESSION['User'] = $this;
```

it is no problem if a field of the object contains those characters